# Replace selected text and have the new text be selected

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk2hs

I'm using Gtk2Hs, and all this GTK stuff is new to me. 
I'm working with a `TextView`. I want to 
replace the currently selected
text with some new text, and have the new text be selected. The closest
I've been able to come up with is:

```
-- Create marks so I can "remember" where the selection was
(startIter, stopIter) <- textBufferGetSelectionBounds buffer
startMark <- textBufferCreateMark buffer (Just "start") startIter True
stopMark <- textBufferCreateMark buffer (Just "stop") stopIter True

-- Delete the currently selected text
textBufferDeleteSelection buffer True True
-- now startIter and stopIter are no longer valid

-- Insert the new text
somehow convert startMark to startIter2 ???
textBufferInsert buffer startIter2 text
-- now startIter2 is no longer valid

-- Select the new text
somehow convert startMark to startIter3 ???
somehow convert stopMark to stopIter3 ???
textBufferSelectRange buffer startIter3 stopIter3
```

The only functions I've found to set the selection require `TextIter`s,
not `TextMark`s. But I haven't been able to find any functions to get a
TextIter from a TextMark. Is this the right procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to do it using `TextMarks`. The function I was looking for was `textBufferGetIterAtMark`.

```
textBufferReplaceSelection 
  ∷ TextBufferClass self ⇒ self → String → IO ()
textBufferReplaceSelection buffer text = do
  -- Create marks so I can "remember" where the selection was
  (startIter, stopIter) <- textBufferGetSelectionBounds buffer
  startMark <- textBufferCreateMark buffer (Just "start") startIter False
  stopMark <- textBufferCreateMark buffer (Just "stop") stopIter True

  -- Delete the currently selected text
  textBufferDeleteSelection buffer True True
  -- now startIter and stopIter are no longer valid

  -- Insert the new text
  startIter2 <- textBufferGetIterAtMark buffer startMark
  textBufferInsert buffer startIter2 text
  -- now startIter2 is no longer valid

  -- Select the new text
  startIter3 <- textBufferGetIterAtMark buffer startMark
  stopIter3 <- textBufferGetIterAtMark buffer stopMark
  textBufferSelectRange buffer startIter3 stopIter3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution. It works, even with the non-ASCII characters I tested. However, I'd still like to know if there's a way to do it using `TextMark`s.

```
textBufferReplaceSelection buffer text = do
  textBufferDeleteSelection buffer True True
  textBufferInsertAtCursor buffer text
  (_, end) <- textBufferGetSelectionBounds buffer
  start <- textIterCopy end
  textIterBackwardChars start (length text)
  textBufferMoveMarkByName buffer "selection_bound" start
```